# Adjust dynamic divs on a page without spaces

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to align multiple divs on my page, that contain dynamic content, as they can be of varying height.

**This is the normal design of divs in my page now:**
[image]

**Now, I would like to have a design like this with css:**

[image]

How can the css for the DIV be modified, to achieve this?

Comment: Share your current code.

Comment: If javascript is an option there's masonry : http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @ATOzTOA Sorry, i cannot share my current code. I don't have permission for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flex box css is what you are looking for, I guess. Here is my jsfiddle:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/KH3b4/4/)

```
.container {
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    box-pack: start;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -ms-box-pack: start;
    box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -moz-box-align: stretch;
    -ms-box-align: stretch;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
}

.container .column {
    max-width:200px;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    box-pack: start;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -ms-box-pack: start;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-box-flex: 1;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -ms-box-orient: vertical;
    box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -moz-box-align: stretch;
    -ms-box-align: stretch;
}

.column .dynamic-content {
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -ms-box-orient: vertical;
    box-pack: start;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -ms-box-pack: start;
    box-align: start;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -ms-box-align: start;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-box-flex: 1;
}
.container .dynamic-content {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px darkgrey;
    margin: 2px;
    background: lightcyan;
}
```

It is pure css, no javascript.
Change the "dynamic-content" divs, the column layouts will align accordingly.

Here is the HTML, copied and pasted from [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/KH3b4/4/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="dynamic-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <p>Sample Sample</p>
            <p>Sample Sample</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dynamic-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="dynamic-content">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dynamic-content">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, ...</span>
            <p>Sample Sample</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="dynamic-content">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dynamic-content">
            <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of sample html that uses this css ?

Comment: I have added some HTML, copied and pasted from the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make 3 `div`'s which would represent columns and then inside each column print/include the boxes. Then just add those `margin-right` you have to the column `div`'s and of course, `float: left;`. On your boxes just have `min-height` so they can stretch depending on the content. For example:

```
<div class = "column">
  <div class = "content-box"></div>
  <div class = "content-box"></div>
</div>
<div class = "column">
  <div class = "content-box"></div>
  <div class = "content-box"></div>
  <div class = "content-box"></div>
</div>
<div class = "column">
  <div class = "content-box"></div>
  <div class = "content-box"></div>
</div>
```

Now, if you care for all of them to end up having the same height, then you will have to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Jonur's answer, I created 3 columns that contain cells with different heights.      http://jsfiddle.net/z4Ygv/2/

The columns are defined and floated left.  I set an explicit height on them for jsfiddle, but when I was using it within my own browser, I had heights of 100% to take up the entire page.

```
.shortcell {
    height:30%;
    width:90%;
    background:#ff0000;
    margin: .25em .25em;
}
.column {
    width:30%;
    height:20em;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.longcell {
    height:45%;
    width:90%;
    background:#00ff00;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: .5em .5em;
}
```

It's a little simpler...and actually marty's only displayed a column to the left for me in jsFiddle